# How can I find out where a specific file descriptor is coming from when I see it using the lsof command?

Tags: java, linux, lsof

Basically I type lsof and I have a bunch of file descriptors that have something like:

```
COMMAND  PID     FD      TYPE  NODE      NAME
java     564     487u    IPv4  TCP       vm3:8003->website.com:5646 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java     564     492u    IPv4  TCP       vm3:8003->website.com:5646 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

And I can't figure out where the file descriptor leak is coming from.  Is there anyway that I can use the FD like `487u` to further inspect where the leak is coming from within the program?  Anything about the FD would be helpful.  If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: The FD number would be relevant only to the program holding the FD open. in classic C-type programs, the FD is just an index to an array that contains the actual file details. The numbers aren't unique across the system, just within that process.

Comment: No ide, I'm running it as an exe on another system and then while its running I do an lsof.

Comment: @Grammin: Unfortunate, if I were faced with this problem I would probably use a debugger.

Comment: I'm also using a java app... maybe there is some java tool that I can inspect the open descriptors with?

Comment: I can't the program only fails in the operational system, so I don't have anything, except the jdk tools and linux system tools.